# Configuring HTTPS on AWS Elastic Beanstalk / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a Rails app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. My setup works fine over HTTP, but I am having difficulty setting up HTTPS access.

I have created a SSL certificate using ACM and set my load balancer to listen to port 443. So I have ports 80 and 443 listening over HTTPS, and both pointing to instance port 80. I have made sure my security group allows HTTPS.

With this new configuration, requests do not seem to get through to the server. Have I missed something here?

Many thanks

EDIT: added ELB listeners image

[image: ELB Listeners]

Comment: Can you post ELB listeners image ?

Comment: Sure, just added as an edit above

Comment: `1) 80/http | 80/http noSSL, 2) 443/https | 80 http withSSL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EB instance port is listening 80 by default. After save, make sure using `https://`.

Also, if using EB url for to check https, certificate will not load. You need to CNAME into yr domain name.

[image]

Comment: That’s fixed it - I had set the wrong instance port. Thank you!